# Is it possible to give, not trade, a Pokémon to another player?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I capture many Pokémon and often want to give them to my friends. Unfortunately, my friends don't catch many Pokémon (so they don't have extras) and very seldom do my friends have any Pokémon that I actually want.

Is it possible to **give**, not trade, a Pokémon to another player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Pokémon must be traded one-to-one, not given. I don't believe there has ever been an option to simply give Pokémon to someone else.

Tell your friends to catch a bunch of low-level Pokémon from the wild, which you can then release when they're traded to you.

Comment: And if they're too lazy to do that, ask them why on Earth they are playing an incredibly grindy game like Pokemon.

Comment: The only way to give pokemon is to use a pokemon storage app like Pokemon Stadium and have your friend connect after you and download your pokemon instead. But there's no such app for this gen and Pokemon bank wouldn't really work for that (you'd have to trade passwords)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible, however, you'll need to download Pokemon Bank, and insert your friend's game into your console.